# Restart Windows Service with Additional Parameters

Tags: windows-services, restart, mysql-cluster

This may be a daft question, but I can't for the life of me find an answer. Basically I am trying to restart a Windows Service, whilst passing across an additional parameter.

In more detail:

I'm setting up a MySQL cluster for testing on my Windows 7 PC.

I've installed a Management Node using:

```
ndb_mgmd --install=ndb_mgmd1 --config-file="C:/msc/config.ini" --configdir="C:/msc/MN1" --ndb-nodeid=1
```

So far so good. But now I have made some changes to the `config.ini`, and I need to restart the service, passing across the `--initial` option.

I can do:

```
sc stop ndb_mgmd1
sc start ndb_mgmd1
```

but that doesn't help with the `--initial` setting.

I've read posts that say to "just add it on the end" e.g.

```
sc start ndb_mgmd1 --initial
```

but that just ignores it.

Surely, this must be a pretty normal thing to do, right?

I'm trying to avoid the need to

```
sc stop ndb_mgmd1
ndb_mgmd.exe . . . --initial
close the window
sc start ndb_mgmd1
```

As that seems like a very longwinded way of doing something that should be simple.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like I might be out of luck.

> [ Known limitation of running MySQL Cluster on Windows:
>
> Running nodes as Windows services is not really practical (as well as
>    software limitations, would still need to activate processes through
>    ndb_mgm)][1](http://www.clusterdb.com/mysql-cluster/running-mysql-cluster-over-multiple-servers)